# "index is out of bounds" error when using readObject with Sockets

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I'm trying to build a simple as3 server/client app.

When the client has connected to the server, it should send a message like "1" to the server.

The server does the following:

```
    private function onConnect(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
{
    incomingSocket = e.socket;
incomingSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
    // You can now read and write data from the socket instance
trace("looks like a connection happened!");
}


private function onData(e: ProgressEvent):void {
    var s:String = incomingSocket.readObject();

 interrupt(s);
}
```

So flash throws me the error:

> RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied
>   index is out of bounds.  at
>   flash.net::Socket/readObject()

The line number flash provides me, shows that the problem is

```
var s:String = incomingSocket.readObject();
```

Has anyone an idea whats going on here?

Thank you!
n

Comment: Please tell us how do you send your message.

Answer (score 1):

readObject is used to read a serialized object on the socket.

If you sent a string, use readUTF, or readUTFBytes if you know the length the string should have.

If you sent a Int, use readInt, or the corresponding method.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it with readUTF, but then it throws me: "Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
 at flash.net::Socket/readUTF()"

Comment: You should get acquainted with Adobe Live Reference. It will tell you that the argument is the number of bytes as uint.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#readUTFBytes%28%29

Comment: Yes, I found out that, so I edited my comment. I now have the problem of: "Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered. at flash.net::Socket/readUTF()"

Comment: When sending data to the server you have to terminate with a null value String.fromCharCode(0). In retrospect on the sever when you send data to the client you have to end it with a null value also in PHP it would be chr(0)